# computing $2^{170}+ 3^{63}\pmod {19}, 3^{175} + 2^{73} \pmod {17}$, etc... by hand

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, exponentiation

I came across several questions like this in the problem section of a book on coding theory & cryptography and I have no idea how to tackle them. There must be a certain trick that allows for efficiently solving such problems by hand.

Comment: First it's a *trick*.  Then it's a *technique*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of tricks. A useful one for your problems is **Fermat's Theorem**, which says that if $p$ is prime and $a$ is not divisible by $p$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

We look for example at $2^{170}$ modulo $19$. Note that $170=9\cdot 18+8$. Thus
$$2^{170}=(2^{18})^9 2^8\equiv 1^9\cdot 2^8\equiv 2^8\pmod{19}.$$

The number $2^8$ is easy to handle. But even here there are tricks, which, for larger numbers, cut down enormously on computation time.  You might want to look up the very useful [**binary method**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) for modular (and other) exponentiation. Our number $2^8$ provides a too simple example. Note that $2^4=16\equiv -3\pmod{19}$. So $2^8\equiv (-3)^2\pmod{19}$.

Comment: Is the line $170 = 9*19 + 9$ correct?

Comment: No, certainly not. It was corrected to $170=9\cdot 18+8$, which was what I had actually used in the computation.

Answer (score 0):

For those specific examples, [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) is the way to go. It states that if $p$ is prime and $gcd(a,p) = 1$, then $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod{p}$$.

For the more general case where the modulus is not prime, then you have [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), which states that if $gcd(a, m) = 1$, then $$a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \bmod{m}$$ where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Answer (score 0):

$$2^9\equiv-1(mod)19$$ $\implies$
$$2^{162}\equiv1(mod)19$$ $\implies$
$$2^{170}\equiv256(mod)19=9(mod)19$$ Also
$$3^3\equiv 2^3(mod)19$$ So
$$3^{63}\equiv2^{63}(mod)19=-1(mod)19$$ So
$$2^{170}+3^{63}\equiv 8(mod)19$$